# Subgraphs of Dynkin Diagrams

Tags: lie-algebras, root-systems, semisimple-lie-algebras, dynkin-diagrams

Am I right in thinking that if we have two semisimple Lie Algebras $\mathfrak{g} $ and $\mathfrak{h}$ with respective Dynkin Diagrams $A$ and $B$, we may find an injective homomorphism of Lie Algebras $\phi: \mathfrak{g} \rightarrow \mathfrak{h}$ iff $A$ is a subgraph of $B$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.  For example, the Lie algebra of type $D_4$ is the algebra $\mathfrak{so}_8$ of $8\times 8$ skew-symmetric matrices. It is contained in the Lie algebra of type $A_7$, that is, the algebra $\mathfrak{sl}_8$ of $8\times 8$ trace-zero matrices, even though $D_4$ is not a subgraph of $A_7$.

Comment: Thank you for this response. In general, is there any information that you can gain from comparing Dynkin Diagrams as to whether or not one may be injected into the other?

Comment: @user366818 Apart from what you say in your post, I don't see any general rule that can be applied.